# No rig main properties options when using the rigify addon

Tags: python, scripting, armature, interface, rigify

As the title suggests, I am unable to see any of the rig main properties options that should be present in the side panel.

As previous questions on this matter have suggested, I have checked the rig id variable in my rig_ui.py script, and it does match the id found in the custom properties field of my rig.

I have tried enabling the 'auto run python scripts' option and manually running the script - both before and after reinstalling blender, but none of these have successfully generated the rig main properties panel.

I am able to generate a rig with rigify, after which I can see the rig layers panel for the new rig, so it appears that this issue is with a specific part of the rig_ui.py script. Does anyone know of a solution to this problem?

Blend file: [image]

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Which release of Blender? Can you add a blend file to your question containing a metarig and generated rig that show the problem?  ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The issue primarily relates to Blender 3.1, however I also tried using the pre-release version 3.2 and had the same problem. I have attached a minimum reproducible example, wherein I simply generated a standard human metarig and produced the default rig without changing any options.

Comment: If you uploaded your blend file to blend-exchange, you need to copy the image tag from there and paste it to your question.

Comment: Ah, right. Let me get that now.

Comment: That should do it but let me know if it didn't work.

Comment: Got it.  Can reproduce that you have no Rig Main Properties in 3.1.  Will look at it in detail as soon as I have time.

Comment: Open a Text Editor in Blender and in the text files see if there is a file called rig_ui.py. Run it and the menus should appear.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, CGdive, but I have already tried running the script in the text editor with no success. Unless rigify doesn't work in blender 3.1, it seems like I may be getting a corrupted script when generating the new rig.